# Recursive Proc in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Is recursive proc posible in Crystal?

Something like [lambda in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516061/can-i-reference-a-lambda-from-within-itself-using-ruby)

I'm trying to do a `y-combinator` in Crystal,something like Ruby one:

```
puts -> {
  fact_improver = ->(partial) {
    -> (n) { n.zero? ? 1 : n * partial.(n-1) }
  }
  y = ->(f) {
    ->(x) { f.(->(v) { x.(x).(v) }) }.(
    ->(x) { f.(->(v) { x.(x).(v) }) }
    )
  }
  fact = y.(fact_improver)
  fact = fact_improver.(fact)
  fact.(100)
}.()
```

The above code was taken from [Y Not- Adventures in Functional Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FITJMJjASUs)

Comment: Brian Cardiff says you should look at https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/710#issuecomment-188261557 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>As far as I know Crystal does not have recursive procs.</strike> But to create Y combinator you don't need a recursive proc. Actually, according to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator):

> In functional programming, the Y combinator can be used to formally define recursive functions in a programming language that doesn't support recursion.

Here is an example of Y combinator written in Crystal using [recursive types](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/alias.html):

```
alias T = Int32
alias Func = T -> T
alias FuncFunc = Func -> Func
alias RecursiveFunction = RecursiveFunction -> Func

fact_improver = ->(partial : Func) {
  ->(n : T) { n.zero? ? 1 : n * partial.call(n - 1) }
}

y = ->(f : FuncFunc) {
  g = ->(r : RecursiveFunction) { f.call(->(x : T) { r.call(r).call(x) }) }
  g.call(g)
}

fact = y.call(fact_improver)
fact = fact_improver.call(fact)
fact.call(5) # => 120
```

**UPDATE**: it is possible to create recursive proc in Crystal with `uninitialized` keyword:

```
g = uninitialized Int32 -> Int32
g = ->(n : Int32) { n.zero? ? 1 : n * g.call(n - 1) }
g.call(5) # => 120
```

Thanks to @mgarciaisaia for the comment.